# Converting document.getElementsByClassName to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code, that i can't seem to convert to Jquery could someone help me out.

Pure JS working code:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("glyphicon glyphicon-comment");
for (var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
     $('#' + elements[i].id).tooltip();
     }
}
```

My Jquery Attempts (both not working):

Attempt 1:

```
 $(".glyphicon glyphicon-comment").tooltip();
```

Attempt 2:

```
$(".glyphicon glyphicon-comment").each( function() {
    $(this).tooltip();
});
```

Example of the button:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="commentTask1" data-original-title="This is comments"></span>
```

Could someone spot the error i've made?

Thnx for your efforts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use another dot `.` without space to target elements by multiple classes:

```
$(".glyphicon.glyphicon-comment").tooltip();
```

and apply the same way for `.each()` method:

```
$(".glyphicon.glyphicon-comment").each( function() {
    $(this).tooltip();
});
```

Comment: Or, assuming the plugin is built for it; `$(".glyphicon.glyphicon-comment").tooltip()`

Comment: Oh, i didn't know that extra dot was required! Works brilliantly now! Looks like i have some required reading ahead( targetting elements with multiple classnames) @oGeez than one works asweel ;)

Answer (score 2):

In Jquery Add `.` to fetch `classname`. you need to add `.` for next class inside **$** sign

**Attempt 1:**

```
$(".glyphicon.glyphicon-comment").tooltip();
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
$(".glyphicon.glyphicon-comment").each( function() {
    $(this).tooltip();
});
```